# Secure files and display them as well

Tags: php, html, image, security, ftp

My question is about HTML and PHP.

This is my setup right now:

- A website where user have accounts
- A FTP server with pictures (currently none)
- Files are currently saved on the website in the "PICTURES" folder (which is accessible by everybody who know the full URL)

So, I would like to know how I can display the images without storing them on the website (which will fix my URL problem).
My idea was to move the files on the FTP server, and when a users logon and request a page with those images, download them through a FTP connection, save them on the website, display the images, and remove them. Which would make them accessible only between the downloading time. But this solutions sounds REALLY bad to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need always to have a place where your images are stored. But, if you don't want to give a user the chance to know where are stored, you can create a system which is used to show the images.

Think about this, if you want to download a file from Mega, you can't access to the URL where the file is stored, instead of that, the server itselfs calls a system who assign you a "key" and you can download the file only through that system using your "key".

You could use a system like "base64" so you can encode your image, and show it using it, or, you can use the "header" modifier so, you can display an image using a PHP code.

For example your image tag will be like:

```
<img src="processImage.php?id=01&user=10&key=123" />
```

So, your processImage will return a "tricky" image, actually not the image, but the code processed by PHP will be returned, like using "imagejpg()" function with the header "Content-Type:image/jpeg" and then the user will not know where the image is stored actually but the img will works actually.